# Can we copy json from exported Power Platform solution and create flows from JSON?

Tags: power-automate, power-platform

Can we create a Power automate flow from a json file? Something like we do for customer connector.

Answer (score 0):

When you go make.powerautomate.com you can import flow/package using 2 options.
yes can export solution but not just json, In addition you can export only flow from make.powerautomate.com and then import it

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the Power Automate Web API.

It has a Create a cloud flow endpoint which includes a clientData property which uses json for objects like connectors & actions:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-automate/web-api#create-a-cloud-flow